# A PHP form that sends emails to different recipients based on options selected

Tags: php, email

I am new to php. I am developing a simple contact us form. In that i want to send email to different recipient based on option selected ie. If user select career option then mail should be sent to `career@xyz.com` & for other than career mail should be sent to `other@xyz.com`. But i am getting emails on only one email even if the user select different options. Pls help.

Below is PHP Code

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Company Name: $company \n Phone: $phone \n Country Name: $country \n Interested: $interested \n Message: $message";

function emailswitch( $key ) {
    $to = array(
        'Career' => 'career@xyz.com'
    );
    $default = 'other@xyz.com';
    return (!empty($to[$key]))?$to[$key]:$default;
}
$to = emailswitch( $subject );

$subject = "Enquiry from Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You! <br /> We will get in touch with you as soon as possible.";
?>
```

HTML is

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" method="POST" action="mail01.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contact-table">
  <tr>
    <td class="contact-heading">Send a <span style="color:#171717;">Message</span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="43%" rowspan="9" align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:30px;"><img src="images/contact-us-new01.jpg" alt="Company Profile"></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="43%" align="left" valign="middle">
    <div class="contact"><label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="width:200px; float:right;" class="validate[required,custom[alphaspace]] for_obj" />&nbsp;   </div>    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="43%" align="left" valign="middle"><div class="contact margin_1line">
        <label>Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" style="width:200px; float:right;" />
      &nbsp; </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
    <div class="contact margin_1line"><label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width:200px; float:right;" class="validate[required,custom[email]] for_obj" />&nbsp;  </div>    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><div class="contact margin_1line">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" style="width:200px; float:right;" />
      &nbsp; </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
    <div class="contact margin_1line">
      <label>Country Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" style="width:200px; float:right;" class="validate[required,custom[alphaspace]] for_obj" />
      &nbsp; </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><div class="contact margin_1line">
        <label>Interested</label>
        <select type="text" name="interested" id="interested" style="width:210px; height:28px; border:#dddddd 1px solid; float:right;" class="validate[required,custom[alphaspace]] for_obj">
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
          <option value="Product">Product</option>
          <option value="Career">Career</option>
          <option value="Information">Information</option>
        </select>
      &nbsp; </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="contact margin_1line"><label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required] for_obj" rows="8" cols="10" style="width:200px; float:right;"></textarea>&nbsp; </div>    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left:142px; padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="contact">
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="butt custom_font" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset" class="butt custom_font" style=" float:right;" />
    </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: then whats the problem ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what your question is here, SureshK. Is the code malfunctioning, or you want to know if you are on the right track?

Comment: Actually i am getting mails only on one email id even if user selects different options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need for a function here. It adds unnecessary complexity, IMO. I'd simply use an [**`if`**](http://php.net/if) statement to check the form input selected and set the `$to` variable accordingly.

```
if($interested == 'Career') {
    $to = 'career@xyz.com';
}
else {
    $to = 'other@xyz.com';
}
```

The `$to` variable will be set according to the form option and it can be used in your `mail()` function later on.

Full code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Company Name: $company \nPhone: 
$phone \n Country Name: $country \nInterested: $interested \n Message: $message";

if($interested == 'Career') { //if career was selected
    $to = 'career@xyz.com';
}
else { //other options
    $to = 'other@xyz.com'; 
}

$subject = "Enquiry from Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You! <br /> We will get in touch with you as soon as possible.";

?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Amal Murali Hey would you mind modifying the example to more than two email, let's say four. Thanks.

Comment: @Labanino: What do you mean *two emails*? Perhaps, ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)? Make sure you include all the relevant details and explain your problem clearly!